# How to store multiple data in a cell inside MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to store multiple dates in a row. Each row has a unique `id` and each corresponding `id` can have multiple action dates. The number of dates may differ for each row. I have multiple ID's and each ID has multiple dates.

```
ID   Date1        Date2        Date3        ...          ...         ...
1    2018-05-19   2018-04-09   2018-08-09
2    2016-01-30   2017-05-04   2016-06-07   2020-05-17   2021-06-23  ...
3    2001-05-06
4    2018-11-05   2013-06-09
```

What is the best way to store multiple dates for a given `id`?

Comment: Why not solve this relationally with a child table?

Comment: Store pairs (ID - Date), where the pair is unique whereas each separate field is not.

Answer (score 7):

Unless each date is a specific property (start date, end date, due date, date created, ...) then storing them as columns is probably bad form.

It is likely that you would be better storing the dates in separate rows like so:

```
ItemDates
===========
ID     (PK)
ItemId 
Date
```

so:

```
ID   Item   Date
 1   1      2018-05-19   
 2   1      2018-04-09
 3   1      2018-08-09
 4   2      2016-01-30
 5   2      2017-05-04
 6   2      2016-06-07
 7   2      2020-05-17
 8   2      2021-06-23  
 9   3      2001-05-06
10   4      2018-11-05
11   4      2013-06-09
```

Or if the dates will be unique per item, you can do without the surrogate key (`ID`) and declare `ItemId,Date` to be the primary key.

If you are not careful this could turn into a property bag (the Entity/Attribute/Value or EAV pattern, which is often considered an anti-pattern) though. *For more specific advice for your use case, you should update the question with a bit more information about what the date values represent in the system that you are modelling.*

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use, you might also consider storing the dates in a JSON array.

```
create table date_table (id integer, date_column json);

insert into date_table (id, date_column) 
    values 
        (1, '["2018-05-19","2018-04-09","2018-08-09"]'),
        (2, '["2016-01-30","2017-05-04","2016-06-07","2020-05-17","2021-06-23"]'),
        (3, '["2001-05-06"]'),
        (4, '["2018-11-05","2013-06-09"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, what others have suggested (child tables) would be the most efficient method, however there are ways to do what you've requested.

**Functions**

Have you checked out this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20738194/8763997 ?

This will automatically group (concatenate) values if they have a non-distinct column relevant to them.

**Manual Method**

Another idea is you could manually store these dates in a string column and separate them by a delimiter such as comma (,).

```
Example: 
ID  Dates
1   '2018-01-01'
2   '2018-03-01,2018-04-02'
```

Then in your application/stored procedure or what ever reads these values, you can then separate them out again.

To insert:

```
INSERT INTO TableName_A
SELECT ColumnName + ',' + @NewValue
FROM TableName_A
```

Or update:

```
UPDATE TableName_A
SET ColumnName = ColumnName + ',' + @NewValue
WHERE ColumnName = @ColumnName
```

Comment: Be wary of encoding multiple values in one. It is definitely a breach of normal form. Only do it if you absolutely know that you will never need to report on the individual values (i.e. you'll never need to count them, or find out the maximum, etc.). Also removing a value would be hassle, and with dates there are locale concerns (what happens if your code runs somewhere where the default date format differs from your country?). Of course concatenation like this would work, allowing for those limitations, and in some circumstances would be acceptable.